# Content of mounted folder deleted on Ubuntu reboot

Tags: linux, mount, chroot

I have created a chrooted sftp user, and mounted a directory to the users chrooted home.

Within this directory I have one directory for each website the sftp user has access to.

When I rebooted my Ubuntu 10.04 server, the content of the mounted folder is gone.

```
/home/chrootedUser/websites/website1
```

To my frustration the website1 directory is gone/deleted.

My /etc/fstab config:
http://pastebin.com/gxz3w9Mg

My mounts (using command mount):
http://pastebin.com/XcGGvGVE

I hope someone can point me in the right direction, please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell now what happend. Could you please check `~/.bash_history` for commands you used to mount directories and show us them?

Comment: sudo mount /home/anotherUser/public_html/chrootedUser /home/chrootedUser/websites -o bind

Comment: Try unmounting `/home/chrootedUser/websites` and looking for your files inside, probably something went wrong and your previous mount didn't work.

Comment: Also ensure that your mounts actually work by reading `/proc/self/mounts`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. When I first rebooted the system without the fstab record the folder did not mount after the reboot. I need it to automount after reboot and not delete the content. How can I accomplish this? I really appreciate your help, thanks :)

Comment: /proc/self/mounts has this record: /dev/disk/by-uuid/b6c003de-0aea-4b0f-a335-d913ed1e6413 /home/anotherUser/public_html/chrootedUser ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0.

Comment: ah, YES!! The content is there when unmounting. Thank you very very much!!

Comment: `fstab` should do the job of automounting. The line in `/proc/self/mounts` you've shown is not this bind mount, it's a partition mounted there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmount `/home/chrootedUser/websites` and your files will be there. Probably your mount didn't work for the first time when you were creating those files. But now it works.

`fstab` should do automounting for you just fine. It's difficult to tell what exactly went wrong, you can read `/proc/self/mounts` to check your mounts.

Comment: Okay, so it really was configured correctly, but something wrong happened? And it should not normally happen?

Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: I can't tell what happend, but your `fstab` is alright, so it should work. What you've copied from `/proc/self/mounts` was a bit strange, so check that you are not mounting anything else to the same mountpoint, just to be sure.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that. I mounted it again, and tried to reboot it. The same thing happened (nginx does not start because dir does not exist).

Comment: @RAH hm, ok, update your answer with full contents of `fstab` and `mounts`.

Comment: thanks, I have now updated my initial post with mounts and full fstab.

Comment: Something is terribly wrong. You `fstab` says “Bind `/home/chrootedUser/websites` to `/home/anotherUser/public_html/chrootedUser`”, but your mounts show that its reversed, that is `/home/anotherUser/public_html/chrootedUser` is bound to `/home/chrootedUser/websites`. I also noticed that you used the wrong `mount` command with arguments reversed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31100/discussion-between-kirelagin-and-rah)